# Highcharts spurious splines

Tags: highcharts

I have spurious lines appearing on a highcharts stock chart, best illustrated by the included screenshot. They are sloping lines, which begin at 0,0 and zoom up to join the 'actual' data lines, as can be seen.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

I can find no mention of it anyhwere.

[Spurious splines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHACn.jpg)

Comment: Your data is not sorted in ascending time so the chart is looping back on itself to connect the splines. That is my guess without seeing any of your code or a reproducible example.

Comment: You were right, thank you very much!

My data is coming from a mysql database, with an auto increment primary key, and a timestamp, as well as the data for the chart.

I assumed, wrongly, that the id would automatically be the sort column, which was a mistake on my behalf. As I deleted chunks of data, there were gaps in the id column, even though the timestamp continued to increment. 

A simple ORDER BY 'timestamp' sorted it.

Thanks again for spotting my oversight!

Max